# Cannot Render Entries to Page

Tags: python, django

I'm making a simple blog for myself in Django, but having a strange issue. I have a simple model as shown below:

```
Entry:
    - title
    - content
```

This is the template I'm currently using:

```
{% for entry in context.entries %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="header">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="title"><h2>{{ entry|title }}</h2></td>
                    <td class="datetime">01.01.2016 00:00:00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            {{ entry|content }}
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#">#some</a>
            <a href="#">#tag</a>
            <a href="#">#right</a>
            <a href="#">#here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I'm getting *TemplateSyntaxError* on the `{{ entry|content }}` line, which is strange.

views.py file:

```
import json, termcolor
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
def index(request, page="1"):
    page = int(page)
    context = {
        "title": "Erdin's Blog",
        "entries": []
    }

    entries = Entry.objects.all()
    r_entries = entries[::-1]
    del entries
    interest = [page*10-10, page*10]

    context["entries"].extend(r_entries[interest[0]:interest[1]])

    print(termcolor.colored(context["entries"][0].content, "green"))

    return render(request, "home.elms.html", context)
```

#### Further Investigation

I already have a single entry on database. I also checked if it's queried correctly into database with `sqliteman`. Assuming I named this single entry as `entry` variable, I called `entry.id`, `entry.title` and `entry.content` and printed out to terminal, that was successful. There's no problem on database.

#### Environment

- python3
- Django 1.8.7

---

---

## A Complete Edit

---

I currently realized the problem was completely different. I called `{% for entry in context.entries %}` but I already called context into template, so the engine was looking for a `context` key inside `context` dictionary.

Comment: Better checkout django template doc first: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language

Comment: Could you also post your `views.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` syntax is for [*template filters*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#filters). To get the model values in the template there is a *dot notation*:

```
{{ entry.title }}
{{ entry.content }}
```

Note that the reason why `{{ entry|title }}` did not throw any errors is that there is a [built-in `title` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#title). But there is no `content` template filter - this is why you see the error on the line containing `{{ entry|content }}`.

Comment: I would accept this as default answer, but it returns blank, not even the block itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply anyway. :)

Comment: @ErayErdin sure, are you sure you need the `context.entries` and not just `entries`? Could you please show the corresponding view? Thanks.

Comment: Or I decided it's the specific answer to the question, so I'll accept this as default answer.

Comment: It's just as in the code above, I just pasted. context is a dict, entries is a list inside of this dict. It has 1 element, but it does not return block strangely.

Comment: @ErayErdin okay, are you sure that this single element is an `Entry` model instance?..you may try just printing it out in the template: `{{ entry }}`, btw, just to check what is it.

Comment: I also added views.py above. :)

Comment: There isn't anything called `entry` in your context dictionary. Call `{{ entries }}` in your template to see what data you are returning from your view.

Comment: @lambo477 I meant print out the `{{ entry }}` in the `{% for entry in entries %}` loop. Thanks.

Comment: It returned blank when I added inside `for` blocks `{% for entry in context.entries %}{{entry}}<br>{%endfor%}`. However, `context["entries"]` returns `[<Entry: 2016-01-02 16:52:38.943831+00:00>]`.

Comment: The problem I do not understand here is it does not raise error in line `{{ entry|title }}` but `{{ entry|content }}`. Is `content` a special keyword in template engine or something?

Answer (score 0):

Since I solved my own problem, I'm writing here for the sake of other users having same problem.

Since I returned a render in views.py as below:

```
render(request, "home.elms.html", context)
```

The template should call for dictionary inside the context as:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
```

not:

```
{% for entry in context.entries %}
```

Comment: This will be the valid answer in two days.